# How to calculate RMS for dataframe column grouped by two column labels?

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe:

```py
         Time  Speed  Magnitude    Meters        Type
0     393.644 -0.122       24.0  0.91 (m)    jump
1     393.836  0.122       47.0  0.91 (m)    jump
2     393.902  0.122       43.0  0.91 (m)    jump
3     393.967  0.122       75.0  0.91 (m)    jump
4     394.043  0.122       59.0  0.91 (m)    jump
..        ...    ...        ...       ...         ...
731  2015.291  1.464       75.0  2.74 (m)  run
732  2015.354  2.073      127.0  2.74 (m)  run
733  2015.417  1.707      256.0  2.74 (m)  run
734  2015.481  0.854       98.0  2.74 (m)  run
735  2015.545  1.951       64.0  2.74 (m)  run
```

There are multiple activities performed at specific Meters jump .91m, walk .91m, run .91m, jump 2.47m, walk 2.47m, run 2.47m, etc

I would like to calculate the RMS of the Speed for a given Type grouped by Type and Meters. Meters and Type are both strings

How would I do this?

I have defined the RMS function as follows:

```py
def rmsValue(arr, n): 
    square = 0
    mean = 0.0
    root = 0.0

    #Calculate square 
    for i in range(0,n): 
        square += (arr[i]**2) 

    #Calculate Mean  
    mean = (square / (float)(n)) 

    #Calculate Root 
    root = math.sqrt(mean) 

    return root
```

I can take the mean by doing:

```
df_full.groupby(['Meters', 'Type']).mean()
```

But is there a way to use my RMS function above instead of mean?

I did try the below code which is working:

```py
def cal_RMS(x):
    return np.sqrt(sum(x**2/len(x)))
df_full.groupby(['Type', 'Meters']).agg({'Speed':['mean',cal_RMS]})
```

But when I use my own function I get an exception: key error

Why does my own function fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define Root Mean Square function like this:

```
def rms(values):
    return np.sqrt(sum(values**2)/len(values))
```

Then if you want to calculate the RMS of the Speed grouped by Type and Meters you can do as follows:

```
df_full.groupby(['Meters', 'Type'])["Speed"].apply(rms)
```

### Toy example code

Using the numbers you provided, after executing below self contained example code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def rms(values):
    return np.sqrt(sum(values**2)/len(values))

df_full = pd.DataFrame(\
[[393.644,-0.122,24.0,"0.91 (m)","jump"],\
[393.836,0.122,47.0,"0.91 (m)","jump"],\
[393.902,0.122,43.0,"0.91 (m)","jump"],\
[393.967,0.122,75.0,"0.91 (m)","jump"],\
[394.043,0.122,59.0,"0.91 (m)","jump"],\
[2015.291,1.464,75.0,"2.74 (m)","run"],\
[2015.354,2.073,127.0,"2.74 (m)","run"],\
[2015.417,1.707,256.0,"2.74 (m)","run"],\
[2015.481,0.854,98.0,"2.74 (m)","run"],\
[2015.545,1.951,64.0,"2.74 (m)","run"]],\
columns=["Time","Speed","Magnitude","Meters","Type"])

rms_speed = df_full.groupby(['Meters', 'Type'])["Speed"].apply(rms)
rms_magnitude = df_full.groupby(['Meters', 'Type'])["Magnitude"].apply(rms)

out = pd.DataFrame([rms_speed, rms_magnitude]).transpose()
```

You get as output the RMS for Speed and Magnitude columns grouped by Type and Meters:

```
Out[65]:
                  Speed   Magnitude
Meters   Type
0.91 (m) jump  0.122000   52.421370
2.74 (m) run   1.666745  142.119668
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last snippet supposed to work exactly as you posted it given that your `df_full` dataframe has columns named `Type`, `Meters`, `Speed`. However if you misspelled any of those e.g. in the DataFrame creation time (or got accidental spaces, tabs, etc.) you'll get exactly KeyError exception.

I would suggest you to run `print(df_full.columns)` and check that column names are exactly as you expect them to be.

P.S. Absolutely irrelevant to your question, but I would suggest to use something like this for the actual computation:

```
def cal_RMS(x):
    return np.sqrt((x**2).sum()/len(x))
```

Difference with `sum(x**2/len(x)` is that in that case you construct np array and then let Python iterate over it as over any usual sequence and sum its elements, but if you do `((x**2)/len(x)).sum()` or `(x**2).sum()/len(x)` the summation is done by numpy - it will be 30-50x faster this way.

Comment: So are you saying my function to rmsValue is correct? I understand the other way is faster but just wondering why my function get a key error

Comment: Yes, your last 3-line snippet works for me without any changes after I create a toy dataframe e.g. like this `df_full = pd.DataFrame({'Speed': np.random.rand(10), 'Type': ['jump' if i < 4 else 'run' for i in range(10)], 'Meters': ['jump' if i < 6 else 'run' for i in range(10)]})`.

Comment: @AlexanderPivovarov, can you please provide some reference for what you wrote regarding `np.sum(a)` vs. `a.sum()`? I don't see anything in the documentation to imply this. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html

Comment: @MarkLoyman `np.sum(a)` and `a.sum()` should be pretty much the same. I was saying that `sum(a)` (not `np.sum(a)`) is much slower than `a.sum()`.